# What is the effect of increasing partition key count on read performance for azure cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

I'm working with cosmos db and I am trying to wisely choose a partition key. I'm wondering what the effect of having a high partition key count will have on read time and indexing. I'm talking 10 keys vs 10000 keys.

Comment: why do you want to have 1000 keys?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score -2):

The number of Partition Keys usually does not matter. All you need to make sure is to select the right Partition key, so that the Read & Write queries are evenly distributed across the partitions.

See [here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey) about selecting the right key for partitioning.

Comment: The number of partition keys does matter, so I'd like an answer that is not a blanket response copied from the documentation which I have already read.

Comment: @toshiomagic you are too cocky for someone asking a question. there are numerous cosmos db team members answers here on SO stating directly the opposite from what you are saying. So, might be a good idea to first say why are you worried about too high partition key cardinality and what impact of number of partitions are you worried about? Then it could be addressed more properly. Untill then i doubt your attitude will earn you any help from community.

Comment: "might be a good idea to first say why are you worried about too high partition key cardinality and what impact of number of partitions are you worried about?" I did say why. I'm worried that it will take too long to index the db. And I want to know the effect on read time. No one has answered that. Everyone just says "It doesn't matter." But it clearly does matter. Otherwise partition keys would not exist. This isn't about solving a specific problem. it's just a theoretical question.

Comment: "there are numerous cosmos db team members answers here on SO stating directly the opposite from what you are saying"

The only claim I'm making is that partition key count affects read/write time. If someone is saying that's wrong, then explain why it's wrong. If it's not wrong, then answer the question. I don't think wanting a straight answer is being cocky.